# How to add html element around another html element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Another day, another problem. I have something like that:

```
<p class="checkbox">
   <input name="cgv" id="cgv" value="1" type="checkbox">
   <label for="cgv">Some text.</label>
</p>
```

Using jquery I want to change this code to:

```
<p class="checkbox">
   <div class="checker" id="uniform-cgv">
      <span>
         <input name="cgv" id="cgv" value="1" type="checkbox">
      </span>
   </div>
   <label for="cgv">Some text.</label>
</p>
```

So, the input element #cgv is inside span and div elements. I want to do this by this code but without any results.

```
$('#submitGuestAccount').click(function () {
        //True if parent is <p> element
        if ($('#cgv').parent().hasClass('checkbox')) {
            $('<span>').insertBefor('#cgv');
            $('</span>').insertAfter('#cgv');

        }
    });
```

Is anyone can help me with my problem ?

Kind regards

Comment: [The documentation](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) can help you with your problem.

Comment: This is it. Thanks

Comment: This is a really bad structure - semantically the "<p>" element should be used to text - ie: paragraphical content - not as a wrapper around non-text element especially inputs. What you should do is change the html structure into a div that wraps around the input. Yes - it can be done (as per leaf's answer)  - but you need to ask yourself - what is the fundamental purpose of this  html structure and it is NOT a generic element with no semantic purpose (that element is the "<div>" which can be used to house other elements.

Comment: This is the native functionally in Prestashop 1.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery API is well documented : http://api.jquery.com/wrap/.

```js
$("#cgv").wrap(
  "<div class=\"checker\" id=\"uniform-cgv\"><span></span></div>"
);
```

```css
div{border:10px solid red}
span{border:10px solid blue}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="checkbox">
   <input name="cgv" id="cgv" value="1" type="checkbox">
   <label for="cgv">Some text.</label>
</p>
```

Comment: I searched in documentation but I don't know how to find this function. Thanks for help.